# figwheel build can't find my core cljs namespace

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen, figwheel

I'm trying to use figwheel build for my project. I use the latest versions of libs and my leiningen version is 2.5.1. My build file looks like this:

```
(defproject figwheel-issue "1.2.3"
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.6"]
            [lein-figwheel "0.3.3"]]
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-3269"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0-beta3"]]
  :cljsbuild {
              :builds [{ :id "dev"
                        :source-paths ["src"]
                        :figwheel true
                        :compiler {
                                   :main myproject/core
                                   :hashbang false
                                   :asset-path "js/out"
                                   :output-to "resources/public/js/example.js"
                                   :output-dir "resources/public/js/out"
                                   :optimizations :none}}]})
```

Normal build works ok. So when I run:

```
lein cljsbuild once
```

I get:

```
Successfully compiled "resources/public/js/example.js" in 0.873 seconds.
```

But when I try to run:

```
lein figwheel
```

Figwheel build can't seem to find my core namespace:

```
Compiling "resources/public/js/example.js" failed.
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: failed compiling file:target/figwheel_temp/dev/figwheel/connect.cljs
 at clojure.core$ex_info.invoke (core.clj:4591)
Caused by: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: No such namespace: core, could not locate core.cljs, core.cljc, or Closure namespace "core" at line 1 target/figwheel_temp/dev/figwheel/connect.cljs
 at clojure.core$ex_info.invoke (core.clj:4591)
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? I created a minimal github project which demonstrates the issue [here](https://github.com/auramo/figwheel-build-issue):

https://github.com/auramo/figwheel-build-issue

Answer (score 1):

Problem was the namespace, it should be:

```
:main myproject.core
```